# Given X a discrete random variable and a classification with probability p for group 1 and (1 - p) for group 2, what is the joint pmf?

Tags: distributions

So, my idea is that we have a discrete random variable $X$ with any distribution. Each value can be seen as the total amount, with the pmf the probability for this amount. We now separate this set into two groups, using a Bernoulli trial with $p$ to group 1 and $1-p$ to group 2.

How do I find the joint pmf of the values in group 1 and 2?

First I thought I needed to find a distribution $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ so that $X = \alpha Y_1 + (1 - \alpha)Y_2$ but this seems impossible for a random discrete distribution, and goes into the problem of decomposition and makes it so that $X$ needs to be decomposible (which it does not have to be, it can be any distribution).

The way with the Bernoulli representation seems like the way to go, and what I can think of is to use the Binomial distribution to find the probabilities for them for two groups, but is this the correct way?

**edit**: I seem to have found the correct pmf for the 'separation' of a one-dimensional pmf using the multinomial distribution, splitting it into $n$ groups. However, how do I make that same split using not a 1-dimensional pmf but rather an $n$-dimensional pmf.

What I had found is 
$P(Y_1 = y_1, Y_2 = y_2) = P(X = Y_1 + Y_2)f_{M}(Y_1 = y_1, Y_2 = y_2, n=y_1+y_2, p_1=p, p_2=(1-p))$
which I believe to be correct (but I may be wrong) and is extendable up to $n$ dimensions.

Now I need to 'separate' an $n$-dimensional pmf into another $n$ dimensional pmf using another set of trials - I am using it for a markov chain.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by an "arrival" for a discrete random variable $X$ and what a "partitioning" might be.

Comment: @whuber hopefully clarified + added what I think to be correct!